# javascript grid control for ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, datagrid

We have a web application designed for pc browsing. For this application we used infraguistics grid control to present information and some of them are hierarchical. We can group by columns, sort them etc.

We want to convert this application to Ipad compatible web application. We are thinking about using jquery mobile, but it is still early stage. There is no grid like control in jquery mobile, there are controls like list and Collapsible but nothing like grids with flexibility like sorting, grouping etc.

Is there is any other options or suggestions.

We are not really focused on Jquery mobile it could be anything but should be javascript based.

Thanks,

Comment: There is grid in [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Comment: but we cannot sort or group it, this grid is more for layout side, i think rather then report kind of presentation. I could be wrong as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may use JSLightGrid plugin. It's responsive, supported by mobile browsers, very light weight and very good in performance, in short good for mibile applications. https://github.com/chanakyachatterjee/JSLightGrid

But you need to write your custom code grouping unless they include it in next version.

It's pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile web frameworks are not as mature as desktop frameworks. The features you're describing are difficult to achieve within the constraints of a mobile environment. I don't know of a mobile framework that will do what you need.

Your options are:

1. Build this yourself using something like jQuery Mobile as a base (I would use [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)).
2. Pay someone to do #1.
3. Alter your iPad design so that it doesn't require this feature.

(Sorry I don't have better news.)

Comment: thanks for suggestions, i might go with option 1 or 3.